# Why does an assignment in a loop affect the rest of the execution of a program?

Tags: java

I have recently coded a very simple program. The *99 bottles of beer* song.

```
public class apples {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int beerNum = 99;
        String word = "bottles";

        while(beerNum > 0) {

            if(beerNum == 1) {
                word = "bottle";
            }

            System.out.println(beerNum + " " + word + " of beer on the wall, " + beerNum + " " + word + " of beer.");

            if(beerNum > 0) {
                System.out.println("Take one down, pass it round " + beerNum + " " + word + " of beer");
            }
            beerNum = beerNum - 1;
        }
        if(beerNum == 0) {
            System.out.println("No more bottles of beer on the wall.");
        }
    }
}
```

How do the code blocks work exactly? I guess my very specific question is WHY does

```
if(beerNum == 1) {
    word = "bottle
}
```

work universally in my little program ? Since the code block doesn't run until the end of the program, how do the later lines of code know that the word bottle should be singular when `beerNum == 1` ?

Comment: Why do you think it does not run until the end of the program? it runs when the sequence of gets to it, which is first inside the while.

Comment: Why do you keep posting the [same code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32576203/trying-to-code-the-99-bottles-of-beer-song-java-beginner)?

Comment: Anything wrong with using that code for someone to help me with code blocks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It knows to print `bottle` instead of `bottles` because initially you have set the `word` variable to `"bottles"`. But if `beerNum` is 1 then word is changed to `bottle` because the if statement

```
if(beerNum == 1) {
    word = "bottle
}
```

checks and changes the `word` variable first in the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

That works because Java reads all lines of code in the order that they appear in the code. It may seem trivial but if you move your block

```
if(beerNum == 1) {
    word = "bottle
}
```

to the end of your while loop, your code won't work (bottles will still be plural) even though the decremental effect still works.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code block sightly

```
if(beerNum >= 2) {
    word = "bottles";
} else {
    word = "bottle";
}
```

This will give you the same output. Hope this helps your understanding better

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no problem with your code. Can you run it in any IDE or use command line to run?! Just trivial thing is, in the code

```
 if(beerNum > 0) {
    System.out.println("Take one down, pass it round " + beerNum + " " + word + " of beer");
        }
 beerNum = beerNum - 1;
```

I don't think we need to check beerNum > 0, just do like:

```
while(beerNum > 0) {

    if(beerNum == 1) {
       word = "bottle";
    }

    System.out.println(beerNum + " " + word + " of beer on the wall, " + beerNum + " " + word + " of beer.");
    System.out.println("Take one down, pass it round " + beerNum + " " + word + " of beer");
    beerNum = beerNum - 1;
}
```

Comment: Yeah that looks a little cleaner. And yeah it does run, I was just wondering about how code blocks work.